# how to get id from URL using php

Tags: php

I have this code on my Search page:

```
<a href="detail.php?id=<?php echo $ido;?>"STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE"><?php echo $nume;?></a>
```

and i also have a `detail.php` page. I need to get the `$ido` value from the URL so that I can use it in the `detail.php` page to retrieve information from the database.

The detail page has a URL like this: `detail.php?id=17` , I need to get the value after the `=`, in this case `17`, into a variable.

Comment: `$_GET['id']`? <padding>

Comment: I know its 6 years old. Im assuming TorrentTrader 3.0, the question highly relevant to torrents-details.php which I believe is what they are inquiring about. This script relies on $id throughout most files, so updating this script file will essentially break the backend functions and template files. Not advised if running TorrentTrader 3.0-svn. $id = $_GET['id'] is line 14 in the file I mentioned.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your detail.php use: `$id = $_GET['id'];` you can then use `$id` around the rest of your page.

Comment: Sorry, Its been 2 years ago, I just wanted to ask! What if I have a url `anypage.php?tacker=123` - Should it be like `$id = $_GET['tracker'];` :/?

Comment: Exactly right. But make sure your URL and `$_GET ['tracker']` use exactly the same word/spelling ("tracker") so it knows which URL parameter the script is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];`

But this will only fetch `id=17`

Answer (score 0):

If still having problem then try:

- To fetch integer value:

  ```
  $id = intval($_GET['id']);
  ```
- To fetch string value:

  ```
  $name = strval($_GET['name']);
  ```